# resources vs resource rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources

I was told that if I only have one "thing", like home (not multiple homes), I should use resource :home, not resources :home in routes.rb.  But then when I look at routes, the POST function seems to want homes#create.  Why plural? I wanted to name my controller home_controller with the class being HomeController.  Do I have to name them plural?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modified quote from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources:

> Because you might want to use the same controller for a singular route (/home) and a 
>   plural route (/homes/45), singular resources map to plural controllers.